# Android set video resolution

Tags: android, video

I trying to set the video size to the lowest resolution available i.e. ***176X144***. At this resolution, video is displayed on the phone but when I record the video and check the resolution it is always ***320X240***. I am using the following code:

```
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(176, 144);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

use CamcorderProfile for API>=8 For setting quality LOW and High.

```
mRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));//176*144
```

check here  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html

Answer (score 0):

`mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(240, 320);`mb u forgot about it . In some phones i see bugs. If resolution more than 320/240  - than video is bugged - with green line .

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am not using media recorder. I am just capturing frames from camera.

Answer (score 0):

Your preview size is not your video recording size.
You can check your supported video sizes with:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> mSupportedVideoSizes = parameters.getSupportedVideoSizes();
```

You can set your video recording size with:

```
MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
profile.videoFrameWidth = width;
profile.videoFrameHeight = height;
mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
```